# Understanding why IP address is in Hostname

Tags: networking, dns

I am trying to understand why some domain owners generate hostnames that include the IP address at which the  host is found, and include those names/IPs in their DNS records. For example [AWS does this with EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html). This practice seems somewhat counterintuitive since the main purpose of DNS is to provide an unknown IP address for a known hostname. I can postulate a few reasons, and suspect that the explanations are organization-specific, but I have not been able to find documentation providing answers for even one case. I am looking for any suggestions for where to find such documentation, or what kinds of search terms might be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It’s an automatically generated name that needs to be unique. So why not use the IP address for part of that name, since it’s also unique? I guess it also makes a machine easier to identify.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious reason for giving an arbitrary but guaranteed unique hostname in the hosting provider's domain is so that there's a stable name for customers to point aliases (CNAMES) in their own domains at.  A CNAME can't point at an IP address, it must point at another domain name.  Also it guarantees that the reverse DNS for the IP address has a valid domain name (hostname) to point at.  If the customer directly uses an A RR then the reverse DNS will be invalid (for the customer's domain name.)